# How can I convert bytes into more useful data?

Tags: java

```java
while (true) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

    bytes = input.read(buffer);
    Log.d(TAG, "byte = " + bytes);
}
```

When I run this code, I can see just `bytes = 32` in Log.

What I planned is showing whole data like 'Temperature:26.7 C, humidity:40%'m but all I can see is just `bytes=32`.

How can I show this received data in original form?

Comment: Have you looked at the data in `buffer`, and at what the documentation for `InputStream.read` says about the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html):

> `int read​(byte[] b)` Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b.

If you are reading raw like this, then you need to continue to read until `bytes < 0` as that indicates done.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    int bytes = 0;
    do {
        bytes = input.read(buffer);
        System.out.println("byte = " + new String(buffer));
    } while (bytes > -1);
}
```

But more simply, if you're reading a string and just want string data, there is a much, much easier way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: `new String(buffer)` would create a string as long as the buffer size (1024). You need to create the string from the first `bytes` bytes only.

Comment: It's not necessary. Particularly for sake of what he's doing. This isn't the start of some enterprise project; he's clearly learning

Comment: The `Log.d` call would suggest he's coding for Android, and yes, it's better to use BufferedReader instead. I was just nit-picking.